# Can "java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary" is detected before rounding?

Tags: java, scala, bigdecimal

java.math.BigDecimal generated by decimal string is sometimes available for setScale(n) but sometimes not.

```
scala> BigDecimal("1.00000000").setScale(1)
res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.0

scala> BigDecimal("1.00000001").setScale(1)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary
```

I know I can catch the exception on thrown,
but is there any way to know if Rounding necessary or not before calling setScale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can set **default rounding** for `setScale`, like:

```
BigDecimal("1.00000001").setScale(1, scala.math.BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `BigDecimal.scale`, which will return the current scale of the BigDecimal.

Calling `setScale` will throw an exception if the parameter is less than the current scale.

Comment: But `setScale(int, RoundingMode)` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a modulo by 1 [0.1, 0.001] and check if the reminder is greater than 0